# How to extend decay estimates $L^p$ to $L^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove the following statement

For $1<q\leq p \leq \infty$ it holds

$\|S(t) w \|_{L^p} \leq t^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}} \|w\|_{L^q}$ for all $t>0$

and for each $w \in L^q(\Omega)$

where $S(t)$ is an analityc semigroup and $\Omega \subset R^{n}$ is open and bounded.

So far I have proved my claim in this cases:

i) $1<q \leq p < \infty$

ii) $1<q<p \leq \infty$

So to finish the proof I only lack the case $p=q=\infty$

I want to know if my idea to finish the test is correct or else can you suggest me how to complete the demonstration?

My idea is this, proof $p=q=\infty$, Let $w \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ then $w \in L^q$ for all $q<\infty$ and apply case i) we get

$\|S(t) w \|_{L^q} \leq \|w\|_{L^q}$

Then taking the limit when p tends to infinity, we arrive to

$\|S(t) w \|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \|w\|_{L^{\infty}}$ this is correct? I assume that $\lim_{p \to \infty} \|w\|_p=\|w\|_{\infty}$

Thanks for your help and your comments I have been improving the post and sorry for my english.

Comment: What is $t$? I assume you mean that $T$ is a bounded linear operator.

Comment: Yes $T$ is bounded linear operator, but i think that this is not essential to complete the proof, but thanks for your comment, i edited the post.

Comment: I still don't see where lower-case $t$ is defined.

Comment: i´m sorry, $t > 0$ is a real number.

Comment: I want to describe the problem in an abstract way. This statement is not true for all bounded linear operators, Really $T$ is very specific

Comment: If $p \ne q$, the statement: "$\forall t > 0 : \|Tw\|_{L^p} \le t^{1/q-1/p} \|w\|_{L^q}$" is equivalent to "$\|Tw\| \le 0$ by considering $t \to 0$ or $t \to \infty$. There should be another place in this question where $t$ comes into play.

Comment: Thanks, I must be more precise, the operator $T$ depends on t, in fact $T=S(t)$ where $S$ is an analytical semigroup. sorry